# Handling Arithmetic Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I've created my own exception to handle situations like arithmetic exceptions, and other situation involving mathematic rules. But When I call it never goes to my Exception for example,on division by zero goes to arithmetic exception instead

Comment: Could you provide a small snippet of relevant code?

Comment: it's hard to say what the problem is unless we can see the exception you defined, and where you are trying to use it.

Comment: ok i will post a part of the code

Comment: ON THE FIRST CLASS
`public BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal val1 , BigDecimal val2)
 {
  BigDecimal result = val2.divide(val1,99, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  return result;
 }`

ON THE SECOND CLASS
`try{ ...} catch (Exception e) {
   throw new EvaluatorException(expression);
  }catch(MyOnException){
   ...
  }`

Comment: You need to catch `Exception` after you catch the more specific `MyOnException`.  Java will execute the first catch block that is castable from the exception that is thrown.  Any catch block after  `catch(Exception e)` cannot be reached.

Comment: so there is no way to catch my exception if there is  a `catch(Exception e)` there

Comment: @Spammer, you need to reverse the order of `catch` blocks. I.e. catch `MyOnException` first, then `Exception`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Division by zero and other "standard" arithmetic errors are handled by the runtime or the class library, which don't know about your user defined exception. You can only use your own exceptions in your own code by explcitly `throw`ing them when it is appropriate.

Of course, it is possible to catch any arithmetic exceptions thrown by the class library and wrap them into your own exceptions:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (java.lang.ArithmeticException exc) {
  throw new MyException("An arithmetic error occurred", exc);
}
```

Comment: My application has a class that deals with the calculations and when throws an error there i had a Exception created by me to deal with simple exception (letter instead of number for example) but when I try to deal with arithmetic error it always goes to that exception

Comment: I have like this
`try{
}catch(fisrt exception){code}
catch(exception I need){code}`

and only goes to the first

Comment: @Spammer, is the exception caught by the first catch block by any chance more general than (i.e. a superclass of) the exception you need? Catch blocks are checked in the order they are defined, and only one of them is executed. So always `catch` the more specific exceptions *before* the general ones.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to catch the standard Java exceptions for these cases, and wrap them in your exception.

```
try {
   int x = 10/0;
} catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
   throw new MyException("My additional text", ex);
}
```

In general, it is not a good idea to add new exceptions unless you will also be adding some additional details.

Comment: Ryan Thanks for you contribution but that i can do. I'm trying to avoid using java exception to use my own for exemplo instead of using ArithmeticException use like "MathsException"

Answer (score 0):

yes, because the exceptions is throwed by jdk's source code, not you. If you want to do some custom logic, you can rethrow your own exception in your `catch DiviedByZeroException` block